# How to group by column, order by a different column, and limit each group to one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
Name      Score
Jim       1
Jim       2
Jim       4
Lisa      2
Lisa      5
Ted       1
Ted       2
Ted       3
```

How can i group by name, order by highest score, and only pick that one row?  So The query would return 3 rows Jim 4, Lisa 5, and Ted 3.

Comment: Q: Is this homework?  Q: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No this isn't homework i tired the usual group by order by limit 1, am in the process of posting what i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the max score, you can [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) name, and use the [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function:

```
SELECT ns.Name, MAX(ns.Score) AS Score
FROM NameScore AS ns
GROUP BY ns.Name
ORDER BY ns.Name ASC
```

I made up the table name, since you did not provide one, switch that for your real table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work, but I haven't tested it:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Score) FROM Table
        GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is trust:

```
select from Table group by Name having MAX(Score);
```